# dynamic csv file processing using shell script

Tags: shell, csv

I'm a new bee in shells scripting and wondering if anyone can help me out with following requirement .
I need to write a shell script code which will read the below tables from a csv file and make sql insert script.
below is the data extracted from csv file

```
Employee,Employee_no,Name,Depart_code,PF No,Salary
Start_employee,,,,,
,234,kasdjf,dev,27,394899
,233,ghasdjf,tes,25,294845
,235,dfsdjf,des,28,404899
end_employee,,,,,
,,,,,
Department,depart_code,depart_name,,,
Start_department,,,,,
,dev,development,,,
,tes,testing,,,
,des,design,,,
end_department,,,,,
```

Comment: You must show us that you worked a little before letting us work! Try something, then tell us where you're stuck.

Comment: This is what i have done so far ,
Splitted the csv file into unique sub files
and 
then grouped all the even and odd files.

the even_Files will contain all the column values and odd files will contain the table name and column values 
Now im unable to remove the table names from each even files into variables 
and export the column to a file 

below is the code

Comment: PID=$$


awk -v f=1 -v r=$PID '/^START_|^END_/{f;++f;next}{print $0 >> "file_"f"_" r".txt";}' nusample_$PID.csv



even_files=$(find -type f -iname "*_*[2,4,6,8,0]_$(echo $PID)*.txt")
odd_files=$(find -type f -iname "*_*[1,3,5,7,9]_$(echo $PID)*.txt")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you could solve it using `awk` commands in a `for` loop over the files where you split your csv:

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUTCSV="$1"
if [[ ! -f "${INPUTCSV}" ]] ; then
  echo error: no input file
  exit 10
fi
PID=$$
#remove everything before start:
rm -i file*txt
echo "" > insert.sql
# split data in ordered list of file
awk -v f=1 -v r=$PID '/^START_|^END_/{f;++f;next}
       {print $0 >> "file_"f"" r".txt";}' "${INPUTCSV}"
MODE="TABLE"
# ordered loop on the above files
for datafile in $(find . -type f -name "file_?${PID}.txt"|sort -n) ; do
  # we start with table definition:
  if [[ "${MODE}" == "TABLE" ]] ; then
    awk -F","  '{
                  {x=""; printf "insert into "$1" (\"" }
                  for(i=2 ; i<=NF; i++) {
                    if ($i != "") { printf x$i ; x="\",\"" }
                  }
                  print "\")"
                }' $datafile >> insert.sql
    # switch mode for each file
    MODE="DATA"
  else
    awk -F"," -v sel="      select "  '{
                  {x=""; printf sel "~" }
                  for(i=2 ; i<=NF; i++) {
                    if ($i != "") { printf x$i ; x="~,~" }
                  }
                  sel="union select "
                  print "~ from dual"
                }' $datafile  | tr "~" "'"  >> insert.sql
    echo ";" >> insert.sql
    # switch mode for each file
    MODE="TABLE"
  fi
done
# remove possible empty inserts:
cat insert.sql |sed '/^insert into  \(\)/d' > insert_final.sql
```

There are many tricks I had to add to this above code to produce inserts dynamically. It will be a little long to explain to you. The thing is you should learn to split your big problems into smaller parts.

Here is the result from your input:

```
insert into Employee ("Employee_no","Name","Depart_code","PF No","Salary")
      select '234','kasdjf','dev','27','394899' from dual
union select '233','ghasdjf','tes','25','294845' from dual
union select '235','dfsdjf','des','28','404899' from dual
;
insert into Department ("depart_code","depart_name")
      select 'dev','development' from dual
union select 'tes','testing' from dual
union select 'des','design' from dual
;
```

Comment: Thanks J for addressing my question and really appreciate the effort . The insert statement is for Oracle db. and the given file is with static number of rows and columns. I was challenged to make it a dynamic script. When ever the script fires it would make insert statement regardless of rows and column and tables definied in the CSV file.  I know we can use external tables / SQL loader to insert but i need to do with shell scripting

Comment: I understood the working of the code.  thanks its working as desired with a couple of changes.